# Send event object to callbacks without event.persist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a component that internally renders an input, the `onBlur` prop to that input is wired to this input. Here is a simplified example:

```
componendDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.blur !== this.state.blur) {
        this.props.onBlur(event);
    }
}
render() {
    return <input onFocus={this._handleFocus} onBlur={this._handleBlur} />
}
_handleFocus = event => {
    this.setState({blur: false});
}
_handleBlur = event => {
    event.persist();
    this._lastEvent = event;
    this.setState({blur: true});
}
```

I want to notify the blur in CDU because there are many events that may trigger a blur event while interacting within the component itself. But I want to notify the component user only when it transitions from focussed state to blurred state. But the problem is that I can't access the event object asynchronously, so the only solution is to do `event.persist()`. But React docs say that it does event pooling for performance reasons. Is there any way I can achieve the same effect without persisting the events?

Comment: [Event pooling](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#no-event-pooling) has been removed as of React v17.0 so `event.persist` no longer does anything. Otherwise move the conditional logic out of CDU and into the relevent handler if there is a genuine (i.e. percievable) performance cost which concerns you.